# Can't access extras after coming back from an intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a **MainActivity** that has a child activity **PatientActivity**.

The **PatientActivity** has a child activity **RecordActivity**.

In **MainActivity**, I `intent` to **PatientActivity** putting an extra content:

MainActivity.java

```
...
listPatients.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id)
    {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PatientActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("patient", patients.getJSONObject(position).toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
...
```

In PatientActivity.java

```
    ...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    intent = getIntent();

    String patientFromJson = intent.getStringExtra("patient");

    patient = Patient.fromJson(patientFromJson);

    ...
```

Now, in **PatientActivity**, at some point I `intent` to **RecordActivity**.

While in **RecordActivity**, when I press the **Up** button (not the back button), it crashes because the PatientActivity.onCreate() couldn't find the reference of **patient**, causing a NullPointerException.

How can I work this out?

Comment: Are you sure your passing the intent to RecordActivity from PatientActivity?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String>hi= new ArrayList<String>();
hi = extras.getStringArrayList("patient");
```

Comment: `Bundle` doesn't have `getStringExtra()` method.

Comment: what if you sent it in an array? also send the int for the location in the array.

Comment: Don't know what are you trying to do... What does this differs from `getIntent().getStringExtra("patient")` that I'm using?

Comment: Oh you are trying to go back and for with this reference? That won't work. I didn't understand your question. The easiest way to save this would be using SharedPreferences if you want to keep it

Answer (score 1):

Done using **SharedPreferences** as @heLLo suggested.

PatientActivity.java

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try
    {
        intent = getIntent();

        String patientFromJson = intent.getStringExtra("patient");

        patient = Patient.fromJson(patientFromJson);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("br.com.metadoc", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("currPatient", patient.toString());
        editor.commit();

        setTitle(patient.getName());
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        String toBeAPatient = getSharedPreferences("br.com.metadoc", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("currPatient", null);

        patient = Patient.fromJson(toBeAPatient);

        setTitle(patient.getName());
    }
    ...
```